# PHP SQL Query to compare values of the search category and the values in the recordsets?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to change my SQL Query to search/compare LIKE with BETWEEN to get all values from the particular field that are >= the search value... not able to make it work so far.

```
  $searchcat = "brand";
  if (isset($_POST['searchcat'])) {
  $searchcat = $_POST['searchcat']; 
}
$selectVal = "LIKE %s";
if ($searchcat == 'quantity') {
$selectVal = "BETWEEN %s";
}else{
$selectVal == "LIKE %s";
}
mysql_select_db($database_prp, $prp);
$query_paperlist = sprintf("SELECT * FROM paperlist WHERE $searchcat $selectVal ORDER BY paperid ASC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_paperlist . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_paperlist = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_paperlist, $startRow_paperlist, $maxRows_paperlist);
$paperlist = mysql_query($query_limit_paperlist, $prp) or die(mysql_error());
$row_paperlist = mysql_fetch_assoc($paperlist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), it is `Between ... And`. it is more like `1<x<10`. I think in your case `Not (Between ... And ...)` is more appropriate which is `not(1<x<10)=x<1 || x>10`. `Not (Between ... And ...)` could be used for greater than operator. You just need to make sure your less than is never gonna be true.